# Convert string ( Revit formula ) to JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, regex, recursion

I'm creating a web app where you can input text (Revit Formula) and convert it to JS Object, to generate some graph tree and validation.

Revit formula is a string consisting of IF and 3 arguments separated by commas, it looks like this:

```
IF (<condition>, <result-if-true>, <result-if-false>)
```

and can be nested

```
IF (<condition>, IF (<condition>, <result-if-true-true>, <result-if-true-false>), IF (<condition>, <result-if-false-true>, <result-if-fasle-false>))
```

For example:

```
IF ( Length < 500 , 100 , IF ( Length < 750 , 200 , IF ( Length < 1000 , 300 , 400 ) ) )
```

Object I want to receive should look like this:
simple:

```
{
  condition: '<condition>',
  resultIfTrue: '<result-if-true>',
  resultIfFalse: '<result-if-false>',
}
```

with nesting:

```
{
  condition: '<condition>',
  resultIfTrue: {
    condition: '<condition>',
    resultIfTrue: '<result-if-true-true>',
    resultIfFalse: '<result-if-true-false>',
  },
  resultIfFalse: {
    condition: '<condition>',
    resultIfTrue: '<result-if-false-true>',
    resultIfFalse: '<result-if-false-false>',
  },
}
```

I tried to use regex but the only thing I came up with is this:

```
IF\(([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*)\)
```

but it does not work with nesting.

Any idea how to convert that formula into an object? I was thinking about using some recursive function but I can not figure out how to do it

Comment: Most likely a regular expression is the wrong tool here. Consider using a proper parser instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
  function parse(str) {
    if(str.includes("IF")) {
     const start = str.indexOf("(");
     const end = str.lastIndexOf(")");
     const [condition, value, elseValue] = str.slice(start, end).split(",");
     return {
       condition,
       value: parse(value),
       elseValue: parse(elseValue)
    };
   } else {
    return str;
   }
}
```

A recursive function, just to give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

To split the part between `IF (` and `)` in to three groups, you could use this helper:

```js
const topLevelGroups = str => {
    const gs = [];
    for (let i = 0, n = 0; i < str.length; i += 1) {
      switch (str[i]) {
        case "(":
          n++;
          continue;
        case ")":
          n--;
          continue;
        case ",":
          if (n === 0) gs.push(i);
      }
    }

    if (gs.length !== 2)
      throw new Error(
        `Parse error: group contains ${gs.length + 1} elements. Supported: 3.`
      );

    return [
      str.slice(0, gs[0]),
      str.slice(gs[0] + 1, gs[1]),
      str.slice(gs[1] + 1, str.length)
    ];
  };
  
console.log(
  topLevelGroups("Length>500,100,200"),
  topLevelGroups("Length>500,100,IF(a, b, c)"),
  topLevelGroups("Length>500,IF(a, b, c),200"),
  topLevelGroups("Length>500,IF(a, b, c),IF(d, e, f)"),
  topLevelGroups("Length>500,IF(a, b, c),IF(d, e, IF(f, g, h))")
  // etc...
);
```

Combining with the recursive logic already shown in the other answer, you can create the desired result:

```js
(function() {
  const input = `IF ( 
     Length < 500 , 
       IF (
         Length < 250 ,
             0 ,
           100
       ),
       IF (
         Length < 750 ,
           200 ,
           IF ( 
             Length < 1000 , 
               300 , 
               400 
           ) 
       ) 
   )`;

  // Remove white space & line breaks
  const clean = str => str.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n|\ )/g, "");

  // Parse a code block
  const parse = str => {
    if (str.startsWith("IF")) {
      const body = str.slice(3, -1);
      const [condition, resultIfTrue, resultIfFalse] = topLevelGroups(body);
      return {
        condition,
        resultIfTrue: parse(resultIfTrue),
        resultIfFalse: parse(resultIfFalse)
      };
    }

    return str;
  };

  // Retrieve the three groups of an IF statement body
  const topLevelGroups = str => {
    const gs = [];
    for (let i = 0, n = 0; i < str.length; i += 1) {
      switch (str[i]) {
        case "(":
          n++;
          continue;
        case ")":
          n--;
          continue;
        case ",":
          if (n === 0) gs.push(i);
      }
    }

    if (gs.length !== 2)
      throw new Error(
        `Parse error: group contains ${gs.length + 1} elements. Supported: 3.`
      );

    return [
      str.slice(0, gs[0]),
      str.slice(gs[0] + 1, gs[1]),
      str.slice(gs[1] + 1, str.length)
    ];
  };

  // Transpile a file by cleaning it and parsing
  const transpile = str => parse(clean(str));
  
  console.log(
    JSON.stringify(
      transpile(input),
      null, 2
    )
  )


})();
```

Just for fun, here's an interactive playground that also `eval`s the result:

```js
(function() {
  const clean = str => str.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n|\ )/g, "");
  const parse = str => {
    if (str.startsWith("IF")) {
      const body = str.slice(3, -1);
      const [condition, resultIfTrue, resultIfFalse] = topLevelGroups(body);
      return {
        condition,
        resultIfTrue: parse(resultIfTrue),
        resultIfFalse: parse(resultIfFalse)
      };
    }

    return str;
  };
  const topLevelGroups = str => {
    const gs = [];
    for (let i = 0, n = 0; i < str.length; i += 1) {
      switch (str[i]) {
        case "(":
          n++;
          continue;
        case ")":
          n--;
          continue;
        case ",":
          if (n === 0) gs.push(i);
      }
    }

    if (gs.length !== 2)
      throw new Error(
        `Parse error: group contains ${gs.length + 1} elements. Supported: 3.`
      );

    return [
      str.slice(0, gs[0]),
      str.slice(gs[0] + 1, gs[1]),
      str.slice(gs[1] + 1, str.length)
    ];
  };

  const transpile = str => parse(clean(str));

  const evalWith = (str, ctx) =>
    eval(`(function() { with(${JSON.stringify(ctx)}) { return ${str}; } }())`);

  const runLogic = (operation, ctx = {}) =>
    operation.condition
      ? runLogic(
          evalWith(operation.condition, ctx)
            ? operation.resultIfTrue
            : operation.resultIfFalse,
          ctx
        )
      : operation;

  document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", e => {
    const input = document.querySelector("textarea").value;
    const ctx = {
      Length: Number(document.querySelector("input").value)
    };
    
    const output = 
      runLogic(transpile(input), ctx);
      
    document.querySelector("pre").innerText = output;
    
  });
})();
```

```css
textarea { width: 100% }
```

```html
<textarea rows="7">
IF ( 
 Length < 500 , 
   IF ( Length < 250 , 0 , 100 ),
   IF ( Length < 750 , 200 , IF ( Length < 1000 , 300 , 400 ) ) 
)
</textarea>
<div>
  Length: <input type="number" value="600">
</div>
<div><button>Evaluate</button></div>
<div>
  Output:
  <pre></pre>
</div>
```